# What is the SQL query to calculate average lease time?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datetime

I need to calculate an average lease time of my cars grouped by a brand.

For simplicity, I have the following `LEASE` table in my DB:

```
carMake | startDateTime | endDateTime
```

My unfinished SQL query looks like:

```
SELECT lease.carMake 
FROM lease
WHERE lease.startDateTime <= {?endDate} AND lease.endDateTime >= {?startDate}
SUM ... ???
GROUP BY lease.carMake ;
```

Example:

```
carMake |   startDateTime   | endDateTime
MB        01.01.2018 00:00     01.01.2019 00:00
BMW       07.06.2018 21:00     01.01.2019 00:00
MB        06.06.2018 00:00     07.06.2018 00:00
```

Result with query range between 06.06.2018 and 07.06.2018:

```
carMake | avgTime
MB        36 hours
BMW       3 hours
```

Database is PostgreSQL

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: What is 36 and 3? Days or months or what?

Comment: Hours, BMW was rented from 21:00 since overlapped only 3 hours

Comment: You wouldn't sum but average (avg) the difference in days*24+24. How you do that differs from vendor to vendor. Your syntax doesn't give an idea what your backend is. If it were postgreSQL as an example: select carMake, avg(extract(epoch from (endDate-startDate))/3600 + 24) as hours 
from leases
group by carMake;

Comment: Hi Cetin, I use PostgreSQL, just wasn't able to find the tag. avg(extract(epoch from (endDate-startDate))/3600 + 24) and also I have to consider for each car Math.max(startDateTime when car is Rented, startDate Query) and the same for endDateTime

Comment: 07.06.2018 inclusive

Comment: I couldn't understand if you are asking something new. Probably it would be better, if you are asking, to provide sample data and desired output with explanation.

Comment: What are startDate and endDate in your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what sql you are using but in SQL Server you can do something like this

```
DECLARE @startdate DATETIME= '2018-06-06 00:00:00'
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME= '2018-06-07 00:00:00'


SELECT LeaseTable.CarMake, AVG(LeaseTable.LeaseHours)
FROM
(SELECT lease.carmake, 
    DATEDIFF(HH, case when lease.startDate <@startdate then @startdate else lease.startDate end, dateadd(DD, 1 ,case when lease.endDate > @endDate then @endDate else lease.endDate end)) as LeaseHours
    FROM lease
where 
    lease.startDate <= @endDate AND lease.endDate >= @startdate) as LeaseTable
GROUP BY LeaseTable.carMake
```

Let me break it down a little:

```
SELECT carmake, AVG(LeaseHours) -- know the lease time avr by car manufacture
FROM
(Select
    LeaseInPeriod.carmake, 
    DATEDIFF(HH, LeaseInPeriod.PeriodStartDate, LeaseInPeriod.PeriodEndDate) as LeaseHours -- Know the lease time in hour
FROM
(SELECT lease.carmake, 
    case when lease.startDate <@startdate then @startdate else lease.startDate end as PeriodStartDate, -- Know the actual lease start date between the perid limits
    dateadd(DD, 1 ,case when lease.endDate > @endDate then @endDate else lease.endDate end) as PeriodEndDate -- Know the actual lease end date between the perid limits
    FROM AS lease
where 
    lease.startDate <= @endDate AND lease.endDate >= @startdate) AS LeaseInPeriod
) Leases
GROUP BY Leases.carMake
```

Comment: I use PostgreSQL, just wasn't able to find the tag

Comment: Can't you simply translate the TSql to PostgreSQL?. It seams that you only need to change a couple of things:
You can find samples here,
http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/dateadd
http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved with a [timestamp range](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) quite easily.

First we calculate the overlapping interval between the desired time and the lease time, from that we can calculate the average in hours:

```
select carmake, avg(extract(epoch from upper(duration) - lower(duration)) / 3600) as hours
from (
  select carmake, 
         tsrange(startdatetime, enddatetime, '[]') * tsrange(timestamp '2018-06-06 00:00:00', timestamp '2018-06-08 00:00:00', '[)') duration
  from lease
) t
group by carmake;
```

The trick is the intersection operator `*` for the tsrange.

Online example: https://rextester.com/KYXB18998

Comment: What if I have different regions and then timestamp doesn’t fit

Comment: Then you should use `timestamp with time zone` rather than `timestamp` - but you should have included that important piece of information in your original question (and the answer you accepted won't deal with that either unless you use timestamp with time zone)

Comment: Why? I need to query based on times in locations, not based on a spot in a timeline

Comment: So which "locations" are you talking about then? there is nothing in your question about "locations".

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT carMake, AVG(endDateTime - startDateTime) AS avgTime WHERE startDateTime <= {?endDate} AND endDateTime >= {?startDate} FROM lease GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: Also I have to consider for each car Math.max(startDateTime when car is Rented, startDate Query) and the same for endDateTime and why GROUP BY 1?

Comment: endDateTime - startDateTime is duration of lease (period between end and start). So query exactly calculates average duration grouped by brand (GROUP BY 1 is a short for group by first column).

Comment: And what if lease period goes beyond query range boundaries?

Comment: If lease period is out of range boundaries, it will be filtered out by WHERE condition and will not be used in average calculation.

Comment: I mean, a car can be rented from 01.01.2018 to 12.12.2018 and I query for a range from 06.06.2018 to 07.06.2018 -> endDate - startDate should be equal to 2 days. If a car is rented from 06.06.2018 00:00 to 07.06.2018 00:00 then the endDate - startDate is equal to 1 day